# How do I reset my sidekiq counters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

In my sidekiq dashboard, I see on the left a box with the counters

```
Processed 168
Failed 111
Busy 0
Scheduled 0
Retries 0
Enqueued 0
```

How do I reset them all to 0?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

To reset processed jobs:

```
Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.del('stat:processed') }
```

and to reset failed jobs:

```
Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.del('stat:failed') }
```

Answer (score 129):

To reset statistics:

`Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset`

ref: [Add reset stats to Web UI summary box and method to API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/pull/888)

Also, you can now clear specific stats:

- single stat by `Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset('failed')`
- or multiple stats by `Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset('failed', 'processed')`

(Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/2475008/tmr08c for update)

Comment: The API has been updated to now accept which stats you want to reset [source](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/v4.0.1/lib/sidekiq/api.rb#L95). So you can now clear specific stats `Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset('failed')` or multiple stats `Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset('failed', 'processed')`.

Comment: This seems like the more preferred solution and IMO should be the selected answer

Answer (score 12):

Also, to reset specific days in the history panel, you can do:

```
Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.del('stat:processed:2015-07-02') }
Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.del('stat:failed:2015-07-02') }
```

And repeat for each day you want to clear.

This is useful if you had a wild job spawning and failing many times more than your usual and you get a history graph with a massive spike in it that makes all your usual history values effectively a flat line.

Answer (score 7):

Just to complement all good answers, reset counters using ruby interactive mode, doing this into console:

```
irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'sidekiq/api'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.del('stat:processed') }
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.del('stat:failed') }
=> 1
```

Answer (score 5):

## 1. Clear retry set

Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.clear

## 2. Clear scheduled jobs

Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.clear

## 3. Clear 'Processed' and 'Failed' jobs

Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset

## 3. Clear 'Dead' jobs statistics

Sidekiq::DeadSet.new.clear

Font: https://gist.github.com/wbotelhos/fb865fba2b4f3518c8e533c7487d5354

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to delete the whole thing along with the history panel for specific dates, here is the helpful snippet:

```
from_date = Date.new(2016, 1, 1)
to_date = Date.today

Sidekiq.redis do |redis|
  redis.del("stat:processed")
  redis.del("stat:failed")

  (from_date..to_date).each do |date|
    redis.del("stat:processed:#{date}")
    redis.del("stat:failed:#{date}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score -6):

This will also reset the history and delete everything from the Redis queue completely

```
Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.flushdb }
```

Comment: This is a nuclear option and will drop everything in that Redis database, not just Sidekiq stats. That means you would lose any new Sidekiq jobs, any sessions, and any other data you happen to be using Redis for.

Comment: Thanks Parker, I was in the middle of something and hadnt finished the post but yes you are 100% correct.

Comment: The nuclear option can be very useful when you're working on a staging/development server. Thank you for this.